# When I run cron I get deleted nodes created again

Tags: cron

I delete **products** and **product displays nodes type** (both powered by commerce module); then all these node are gone.

After this, I run cron and I get all those (deleted) node back in my site.

How can I trace this problem?

Comment: Have you used http://drupal.org/project/feeds to import content into your site? In that case perhaps you have configured your feed to make a import everytime cron runs? In that case I think you should set `Minimum refresh period` to none.

Comment: yes I did. But I just updated all modules, run database update and the problem is no showing up. I'll keep what you said in mind anyway. Thanks.

Comment: You was absolutely right, I had one importer configured to run every 30mins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you used [`drupal.org/project/feeds`](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) to import content into your site? In that case perhaps you have configured your feed to make a import every time cron runs? In that case I think you should set Minimum refresh period to none.

Also, here is a thread facing the same problem: [Delete feed, ron cron, feed comes back](http://drupal.org/node/1040780)